# NAudio getting samples from current position

Tags: c#, naudio

How can I get "current sound"'s samples from ISampleProvider if I know how many milliseconds the audio file have been playing for? If this doesn't make any sense, and I don't understand something, please link the source which I can learn from

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.